# Elasticsearch TransportError(400, u'MapperParsingException

Tags: python, indexing, elasticsearch, lucene

I have run the following python code with no errors. But now I am having this

```
TransportError(400, u'MapperParsingException [Analyzer [whitespace_analyzer] not found for field [job style]]'
```

The code is :

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import xlrd

es = Elasticsearch()



es.indices.create("we_doing",body={
      'settings': {
        "analysis": {
         "tokenizer":{
            "camel":{
                    "type": "pattern",
                    "pattern":"([^\\\\p{L}\\\\d]+)|(?<=\\\\D)(?=\\\\d)|(?<=\\\\d)(?=\\\\D)|(?<=[\\\\p{L}&&[^\\\\p{Lu}]])(?=\\\\p{Lu})|(?<=\\\\p{Lu})(?=\\\\p{Lu}[\\\\p{L}&&[^\\\\p{Lu}]])"
                }},

     "analyzer": {
        "nGram_analyzer": {
           "type": "custom",
           "tokenizer": ["whitespace","camel"],
           "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding"

           ]
        },
        "whitespace_analyzer": {
           "type": "custom",
           "tokenizer": ["whitespace","camel"],
           "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding"
           ]
        }}}}}, ignore = 400 ) 

mapping = {
"we_data": {

    "properties": {
        "job id": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"},

        "job style":{
        "type":"string",

        "index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": 'whitespace_analyzer',


    },

        "location": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"},
        "experience": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"},
        "post date": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"},
        "job description": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"},

    }}}


es.indices.put_mapping(index="we_doing", doc_type="we_data", body=mapping)
```

It was working perfectly. now i am in so much trouble. Its going to be live in 2 days. please be of some help .

Comment: what have you done for it not to be working? these kind of issues don't happen alone. They need human help!

Comment: In my memory I havent done anything. if i am specyfing standard analyzer it is working. Why it is not taking custom analyzers ??? Please help .

Comment: did you try to send the raw json mapping with the curl command?

Comment: No i have modified it in correct json format with respective field names

Answer (score 0):

Only one tokenizer can be used by an analyzer(per [Elasticsearch Analysis reference page](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html)).  You'll need to use a TokenFilter to take to the place of one of them ([Word Delimiter Token Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html#analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter) should do nicely), or use a Tokenizer that accomplishes both.